# Show FaceBook profile in my App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to show facebook profile in my app,
until now i use the method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/userId"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But i want to know if there is a possible to show the profile inside my app and not open facebook app for this.
I want to do it because the problem that when there is no FaceBook app in the iPhone so the user can't see the profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a webView to display this.

1. Make the `UIWebView`, set the `frame`, add to `view`
2. load the page with that `url`, look into this function:

   `(void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL`

and be sure to checkout the `UIWebView` class reference here: [`UIWebView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)